# Android aar file dependencies not found in used project

Tags: android, aar, library-project

I created library project and used some dependencies.Then i build 'aar' file and import it in to a new project as a new module.
The issue is dependencies of aar project are not imported in to the new project environment? Do you have any idea?

[image: My library Gradle]

[image: My Project Gradle]

[image: Build Error]

Comment: did you use the recommend way to import the library?

Comment: yes using File->New->New Module->Import AAR package

Comment: What you use in Gradle ? (compile or implementation)

Comment: implementation project(':cui')

Comment: NO I mean what use in library's gradle ?

Comment: used implementation for the both projects

Comment: Please post gradle of library.

Comment: edited the post. sorry i have no permission to preview the image

Comment: only res File not found or all class not found ?

Comment: chek [here](https://github.com/Vigi0303/fat-aar-plugin) - It may be solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

aar module can not exported dependency aar,if you want to use dependency aar in other module you should dependent it in your new module.

for your case,maybe api will solve your problem. The doc about api and implementation check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies)

Comment: Thanks. do you have any reference from android side?

Comment: No,I didn't find that,but I've tried to export it in my aar module several times like you and I'm failed.Finnally,I created dependencies in new moulde which should included in exported aar module.

Comment: Hi,I reedited my post,you can change implementation to api ,that will address your problem.I made a mistake in first time,sorry about that.

Comment: tried using api in library module. still have the problem.